# Priority visa converted into standard visa

Tags: visas, uk, study

I have applied for uk student visa through priority service, but after 5 days  I got mailed from VFS that We not able to to make decisions on your application within priority visa days, so we will continue to this application through standard visa ( normal customer service) target of 15 days. So I want to know why they decided that, although  I paid priority visa. So why they are not providing me that service?

Answer (score 3):

The VFS site states that using the Priority Visa service does not guarantee that your application will be successful. All visa applicants must meet the requirements of the UK Immigration Rules. If your application is not straightforward for any reason, it may not be possible to meet the priority timescale https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/th/en/premium-services/priority-visa
The priority fee is non-refundable if an application is unsuccessful or takes longer to process.

Comment: Can you tell what is the reason behind that decision?

Comment: @Rehan The priority fee is non-refundable if an application is unsuccessful or takes longer to process. A delay could be due to various factors eg queries over supporting documents or other verification checks. Only VFS will be able to explain.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I’m really appreciate with you and your service.

Comment: @Rehan a minor correction: only UKVI could explain why; VFS cannot, as it is a processing centre and not involved in any way in the decisionmaking.