# Late UK visa application (2-3 weeks before departure date)

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas

I just want to inquire regarding the UK Visa application. is it possible i can apply for the UK visa 2-3 weeks before my departure date?

Answer (score 3):

The standard published timescale is 15 working days, unless you are applying from a location where a priority application is possible (which does not guarantee a quicker response, however [Priority visa converted into standard visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121607/priority-visa-converted-into-standard-visa/121608?noredirect=1#comment299037_121608)) You can check the timescale for your location via https://www.gov.uk/visa-processing-times. You can of course apply at short notice but you risk not getting the decision in time if your departure date is not flexible.